# How does filter function in R works

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand how filter function works in R.I saw below code

```
x <- 1:100
filter(x, filter=.50,method="recursive")
```

And I got output as

```
 [1]   1.00000   2.50000   4.25000   6.12500   8.06250  10.03125  12.01562  14.00781  16.00391
 [10]  18.00195  20.00098  22.00049  24.00024  26.00012  28.00006  30.00003  32.00002  34.00001
 [19]  36.00000  38.00000  40.00000  42.00000  44.00000  46.00000  48.00000  50.00000  52.00000
 [28]  54.00000  56.00000  58.00000  60.00000  62.00000  64.00000  66.00000  68.00000  70.00000
 [37]  72.00000  74.00000  76.00000  78.00000  80.00000  82.00000  84.00000  86.00000  88.00000
 [46]  90.00000  92.00000  94.00000  96.00000  98.00000 100.00000 102.00000 104.00000 106.00000
 [55] 108.00000 110.00000 112.00000 114.00000 116.00000 118.00000 120.00000 122.00000 124.00000
 [64] 126.00000 128.00000 130.00000 132.00000 134.00000 136.00000 138.00000 140.00000 142.00000
 [73] 144.00000 146.00000 148.00000 150.00000 152.00000 154.00000 156.00000 158.00000 160.00000
 [82] 162.00000 164.00000 166.00000 168.00000 170.00000 172.00000 174.00000 176.00000 178.00000
 [91] 180.00000 182.00000 184.00000 186.00000 188.00000 190.00000 192.00000 194.00000 196.00000
[100] 198.00000
```

I'm not getting how this output generated.Can you please help me understand?

Comment: Where did you see that code?

Comment: You used the method 'recursive', so an autoregression is done

Comment: Are you talking about `filter` from `stats` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `?stats::filter`, if we specify the `method` as `"recursive"` an autoregression is used and the `filter` argument takes a vector of filter coefficients in reverse time order.  The recursive filter is based on

[image]

So, using the same principle, we multiply the filter coefficient i.e. 0.5 with the previous value and add with the current value

```
x1 <- x[1]
x2 <- x[2] + 0.5 * x1
x2
#[1] 2.5
x3 <- x[3] + 0.5 * x2
x3
#[1] 4.25
```